# Examples of non linear Lie-Groups

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

When looking for a non linear Lie Group I always find the example of the Heisenberg Group $H$ modulo a normal Group $N$. Where the matrix of the two groups are of this form

$$
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & a & c \\
 0 & 1 & b \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
N = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & n \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Do you know any other simple example of non-linear Lie Group?

Comment: By nonlinear I suppose you mean having no faithful finite-dimensional representation. For $n \geq 2$ the universal cover $\widetilde{SL}(n, \Bbb R)$ of $SL(n, \Bbb R)$ is such an example.

Answer (score 1):

As Travis said, the universal cover of the a special linear group is not a matrix group. Another classical  example is the metaplectic group.

Also any nilpotent lie group wich is non simply connected is not a matrix group.

See Wolfgang Ziller lecture notes on lie groups and representations p40 as reference.

Edit: the reduced heissenber group isnt a linear group also

Comment: I've already downloaded them early this morning, but thanks anyway