# What class of Lie groups embed in a general linear group?

Tags: group-theory, differential-topology, lie-groups, matrix-analysis

It’s a non trivial fact that every compact Lie groups embeds as a subgroup of SO(n), what larger class of Lie groups can one consider that necessarily embeds in GL(n)?
Possibly locally compact or finitely generated+ some condition. I know residual finite + finitely generated is insufficient.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608027/examples-of-non-linear-lie-groups) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62624/complex-lie-group-without-faithful-real-representations) are a few non-examples.

Comment: What do you mean by "residually finite" or "finitely generated" for a Lie group?

Comment: Later I found that this might have the answer: https://mathoverflow.net/q/64195/41139

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the answer for finitely generated groups (the proof is rather nontrivial):

**Definition.** A group $\Gamma$ is said to  have a $p$-congruence structure with the bound $c$ if $\Gamma$ has a descending chain of finite index normal subgroups
$$
\Gamma=N_0\supset N_1 \supset N_2 \supset ...
$$
such that

(1) $\bigcap_i N_i=\{1\}$.

(2) $N_1/N_i$ is a finite $p$-group for each $i>1$;

(3) Each quotient group $N_i/N_j$ ($1\le i<j$) is generated by $c$ elements.

Note that part (1) is equivalent to the residual finiteness of $\Gamma$.

**Theorem.** Let Γ be a finitely generated group. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

(A) Γ is isomorphic to a subgroup of the group $GL_n({\mathbb C})$ for some $n$.

(B) Γ has a $p$-congruence structure with some bound $c$ for some prime $p$.

See:

Alexander Lubotzky, [**A group theoretic characterization of linear groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(88)90190-1), J. Algebra 113, No. 1, 207-214 (1988). [ZBL0647.20045](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0647.20045).

Answer (score 2):

This is a partial answer that only applies to connected groups.

Every Lie algebra embeds into the lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ for some $n$. This is [Ado's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ado%27s_theorem). So for every Lie algebra there is at least one Lie group with that Lie algebra embedding into $GL(n)$.

Because of the relation between different connected Lie groups with the same Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ (they are all quotients of their joint universal covering group $\tilde{G}$ by discrete subgroups $S$ of the center $Z$ of $\tilde{G}$) it is a topological matter. The fundamental group of $G := \tilde{G}/S$ is, if I am not crazy, isomorphic to $S$ and is hence enough to single out $G$ from its locally-but-not-necessarily-globaly isomorphic brothers and sisters.

Now whether the Lie-algebra embedding of $\mathfrak{g}$ into $\mathfrak{gl}(n)$ globalizes to a Lie group embedding of $G$ into $GL(n)$ depends only on if the fundamental group of $G$ is 'compatible' with the fundamental group of $GL(n)$, but I forgot the precise notion of compatibility here.